# Why would a shower pump turn on when not required?

Tags: shower, hot-water

In my long loft I have two shower pumps and two hot water cylinders.  The pump/tank on the far end of the loft is for 1 bathroom and the pump/tank on the near end is for another bathroom.

After running the shower at the far end of the house, when I turn the shower off, the shower pump at the near end of the loft starts for 1 second, stops for 1 second and then repeats.  It goes on for about 3 or 4 minutes.  Obviously, with all this starting and stopping, it reverberates through the house quite loudly (it sounds like it's trying to escape!)

Why would this happen?

p.s. not enough rep to create tags 'shower-pump' and 'hot-water-cylinder'

Comment: Bad pressure switch on the pump?

Comment: p.p.s. ...which tags would then have to be recombined into the tags you did use, so perhaps there's good cause for requiring adequate rep to create tags, so we don't get buried in irrelevant tag-over-specificy, at least until you SHOULD know better.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Got a plumber round tomorrow, will put that to him.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, are you saying that you think my tags are irrelevant? I'm no DIY expert, and gaining rep will not make me one. I merely added that so that someone with enough rep could add them if they see fit.

Comment: Not irrelevant - over-specific. The ones on here seem appropriate to me. One test you might try - what happens if you shut off the offending shower s-l-o-w-l-y, rather than quickly/normally? I'm guessing there might an oscillation set up by a quick/normal shutoff that might be avoided by a slower shutoff.